# Is it realistic to use AWS Lambda as an http backend for a mobile application?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I currently am considering doing an AWS backend using either an EC2 instance, or AWS Lambda with Api Gateway. I know all about the basics of Lambda like how there is a cold start, you can only execute for a set maximum time, etc.

The part I am concerned about is whether AWS Lambda can handle the amount of HTTP requests that would need to be made for a full scale mobile application.

Here is an example situation I am considering. Lets say my app has 100,000 users. Lets say each user makes 12 http requests every minute on the app. So that means 12 / 60 seconds = 0.2 http requests per second per user. This means that if my app has 100,000 concurrent users it would be making 100,000 * 0.2 = 20,000 requests per second.

Is it possible for 1 lambda function to serve 20,000 requests per second? One of my bigger http requests that I was testing took 0.2 ms to run from start to finish. This is what is making me consider switching to an EC2 instance instead of AWS Lambda.

I know it is "possible" to do an http AWS lambda backend, but is it realistic with this kind of traffic?

Comment: You can [calculate](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-concurrency.html#calculating-concurrency) the required concurrency: (average requests per second) * (average request duration in seconds). Then you can review the reserved and provisioned concurrent alternatives and relevant quotas. If you're hoping for 0.2ms duration and supporting 20k RPS for some number of hours/day (not sure how many hrs/day, but you probably have an idea) then the economics of EC2 begin to look better, in all likelihood.

Comment: Related discussion: [Scaling Lambda to 30K RPS](https://www.serverlessguru.com/blog/scaling-aws-lambda-to-30k-request-per-second).

Answer (score 0):

There's a quota per account and per function limiting concurrent executions. By default it is set to 1000 but you can request an extension.
The documentation mentions tens of thousands which is already a lot (check https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-limits.html).

There's also a concurrency scaling rate, that will limit the creation of 1000 new execution environment every 10 seconds (check https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/scaling-behavior.html).
So if all your users connect at the same time, some connections will be rejected. They will be accepted after a couple of minutes, time needed to scale the environment.

It is difficult to predict how many users will connect in the next second. You can experience the same issue with EC2 instances if you don't have enough capacity and it takes too much time to spawn new instances.

The main comparison will be the cost. If your usage is high and constant, EC2 could be more interesting (capacity based). Conversely if your usage is infrequent, lambda is great (usage based).